# Prelogin error while connecting to SQL server in java

Tags: java, sql, connection

i am trying to connect SQLserver in java. i could not do it in spring so created a main function in same project and still not successful. i am getting the following error:

```
Oct 22, 2015 12:07:05 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
WARNING: ConnectionID:1 Prelogin error: host **DB-NAME** port 3306 Unexpected response type:78
```

my main method is as follows.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{    
    Connection conn = null;
    String dbName = "envtracker";
    String serverip=**"DB-NAME"**;
    String serverport="3306";
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+serverip+":"+serverport+";databaseName="+dbName+"";
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet result = null;
    String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    String databaseUserName = "user-id";
    String databasePassword = "paswd";
    System.out.println("here-1");
    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, databaseUserName, databasePassword);

        System.out.println("here-2");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        result = null;
        String pa,us;

        System.out.println("here-3");
        result = stmt.executeQuery("select * from table-1 ");
        System.out.println("here-4");
        while (result.next()) {
            us=result.getString("uname");
            pa = result.getString("pass");              
            System.out.println(us+"  "+pa);
        }
        System.out.println("here-5");
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

can somebody please help me here. I have tried to search on the solution at multiple places. but could not find anything related.

Comment: Did you try googling the error? Are you sure you are running SQL Server on port 3306 (normally used by MySQL) and not port 1433?

Comment: SQL server defaults to port 1433. You've confirmed your SQL instance is running on port 3306?

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 solutions to this problem :

1. check if your DBA actually installed Sql server with correct port number or if the person was from mysql background and ended up in a sql profile. this happened in my case.
2. check if you are actually using SQL server. change the drivers class to my sql and vice versa and it might help.